# Default Operator Solr and BooleanQuery building

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I create the boolean query programically. Like this:

```
    BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
    for (Iterator<String> it = guids.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        String guid = it.next();
        query.add(new BooleanClause(
                  new TermQuery(
                       new Term("guid",guid)
                               ),
                  BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD));
    }
```

Then I return it from parser. in parser I set

```
parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);
```

The problem is that is still return a query like

```
guid:dafafafa guid:dadafafaf
```

which with default operator means:

```
guid:dafafafa AND guid:dadafafaf
```

but what I want is:

```
guid:dafafafa OR guid:dadafafaf
```

why doesnt query parser take care of adjusting for default operator????

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite know what you mean by it "returns a query like"...  I assume, however, that you mean that you get that from something like `Query.toString()` on the resultant query.

The query passed out of the parser no longer has anything to do with the parser.  There is no default operator on that query, the default operator only applies to parsing a textual query passed into it.  `Query.toString` and other similar methods make a best-effort to represent an arbitrarily complex query in string form.  In doing this, they generally will not use AND/OR syntax, but rather +/- syntax, which more closely correlates to the representation of actual lucene queries, which have clauses set to `SHOULD`, `MUST`, `MUST_NOT`.

Rereading, I may be misunderstanding, and you may be simply constructing the entire query manually.  But if you aren't passing a query string through the QueryParser, what would the QueryParser have to do with anything at all?

Comment: Im writing a custom Query Parser for Solr. In order to implement it I use Extendable Query parser from lucene [here is the description](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/ext/ExtendableQueryParser.html). Then for each field there is an extension which return a query. This set of queries is then returned to Solr **QParser.parser**

Comment: I see.  The default operator logic will take affect on comprehending the query string though, not transforming `Query` objects.  I believe, if you are implementing the logic to build the `Query` yourself, it will also fall to your implementation to handle the defaultOperator.  If you explicitly set a Clause with `BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD`, it would seem very odd for that clause to then be overridden by a default operator.